# Htaccess Redirect - www to subdomain with added folder structure

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I'm looking to redirect property listings to a new subdomain and domain structure. For example, I would like to redirect

```
http://www.example.com/idx/details.php?thenALongString...
```

to

```
http://mls.example.com/idx/3494/details.php?thenALongString...
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^idx/details.php http://mls.example.com/idx/3494/details.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks @Teun. When added it redirected to the right subdomain but it left off the dynamic ending string. So the redirect looked like this: http://mls.example.com/idx/3494/details.php Is there a way to have a dynamic ending. My example has this after details.php (?idxID=003&listingID=607267). As you can see the listing id could be very different.

Comment: Aha.. I updated my answer, I hope it works (I'm unable to test it myself right now).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. I used the following:

`RedirectMatch 301 /idx/details.php(.*) http://mls.lisasellspontevedra.com/idx/3494/details.php`

The dynamic string on the old URL is transferred over to the end of the new location.